# How to find all taxicab numbers less than N?

Tags: algorithm

A taxicab number is an integer that can be expressed as the sum of two cubes of integers in two different ways: `a^3+b^3 = c^3+d^3`. Design an algorithm to find all taxicab numbers with a, b, c, and d less than N.

Please give both the space and time complexity in terms of N.
I could do it in `o(N^2.logN)` time with `O(N^2)` space.

Best algorithm I've found so far:

Form all pairs: `N^2`
Sort the sum: `N^2  logN`
Find duplicates less than N

But this takes `N^2` space. Can we do better?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: specify if this is homework please

Comment: Actually this is a job interview question but that tag seems to have been deleted

Comment: why all the downvotes ? looks like a totally legit question for SO!

Comment: @alfasin "Hi give me the codes plz" is an automatic downvote from me.

Comment: @Deestan: I gave an algorithm now. I am not asking for code just the algorithm.

Comment: @Deestan no-one asked you to code, that an algorithmic question, plus, Bruce said what were the results that he achieved and asked if anyone can do better, read the last line please!

Comment: @alfasin: I actually wrote that later on...after the first comment...that was a mistake

Comment: Oh... still, since the mistake was corrected, I would expect a remove of an unnecessary down-vote.

Comment: Actually, form all pairs is way more than N^2, but even if we assume that it's N^2, Sort the sum should be `O(N^2 log N^2)`

Comment: @alfasin: log N^2 = 2*log N. And the number of pairs is NC2 ~ N^2.

Comment: check this, please http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815/find-taxicab-numbers-in-on-time

Comment: @mishadoff: Can the space complexity be improved?

Comment: @Bruce I can't find better than O(N^2)

Comment: @Bruce your pleasure, note that StackExchange platform much bigger than stackoverflow.com where you can find solution

Comment: It can be done in `O(n^2)` space & *average* time, using a `HashMap:Sum->List<Pair>` (a hash map that its keys are the sums, and the values are pairs for this sums)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The time complexity of the algorithm can't be less than **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** in any case, since you might print up to **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** taxicab numbers.

To reduce space usage you could, in theory, use the suggestion mentioned here: [little link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2822/17694). Basically, the idea is that first you try all possible pairs **a, b** and find the solution to this:

> a = 1 − (p − 3 * q)(p<sup>2</sup> + 3 * q<sup>2</sup>)
>
> b = −1 + (p + 3 * q)(p<sup>2</sup> + 3q<sup>2</sup>)

Then you can find the appropriate **c, d** pair using:

> c = (p + 3 * q) - (p<sup>2</sup> + 3 * q<sup>2</sup>)
>
> d = -(p - 3 * q) + (p<sup>2</sup> + 3 * q<sup>2</sup>)

and check whether they are both less than N. The issue here is that solving that system of equations might get a bit messy (by 'a bit' I mean **very** tedious).

The **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** space solution is much simpler, and it'd probably be efficient enough since anything of quadratic time complexity that can run in reasonable time limits will probably be fine with quadratic space usage.

I hope that helped!

Answer (score 27):

> But this takes N^2 space. Can we do better?

There exists an **O(N) space solution** based on a **priority queue**. Time complexity is **O(N^2 logN)**. To sketch out the idea of the algorithm, here is the matrix M such that M[i][j] = i^3 + j^3 (of course, the matrix is **never created in memory**):

```
0    1    8    27    64    125
1    2    9    28    65    126
8    9    16   35    72    133
27   28   35   54    91    152
64   65   72   91    128   189
125  126  133  152   189   250
```

Observe that every line and every row is sorted in ascending order. Let PQ be the priority queue. First we put the biggest element in the priority queue. Then perform the following, as long as the PQ is not empty:

1. Pop the biggest element from PQ
2. add adjacent element above if the PQ doesn't have any element from that row
3. add adjacent element on the left if the PQ doesn't have any element from that column, and if it is not under the diagonal of the matrix (to avoid redundant elements)

Note that

1. You don't need to create the matrix in memory to implement the algorithm
2. The elements will be popped from the PQ in descending order, from the biggest element of the matrix to its smallest one (avoiding elements from the redundant half part of the matrix).

Everytime the PQ issues the same value twice then we have found a taxicab number.

As an illustration, here is an implementation in C++. The **time complexity is O(N^2 logN)** and **space complexity O(N)**.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned int value_type;

struct Square
{
    value_type i;
    value_type j;
    value_type sum_of_cubes;
    Square(value_type i, value_type j) : i(i), j(j), sum_of_cubes(i*i*i+j*j*j) {}
    friend class SquareCompare;
    bool taxicab(const Square& sq) const
    {
        return sum_of_cubes == sq.sum_of_cubes && i != sq.i && i != sq.j;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Square& sq);
};

class SquareCompare
{
public:
    bool operator()(const Square& a, const Square& b)
    {
    return a.sum_of_cubes < b.sum_of_cubes;
    }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Square& sq)
{
    return os << sq.i << "^3 + " << sq.j << "^3 = " << sq.sum_of_cubes;
}

int main()
{
    const value_type N=2001;
    value_type count = 0;
    bool in_i [N];
    bool in_j [N];

    for (value_type i=0; i<N; i++) {
    in_i[i] = false;
    in_j[i] = false;
    }

    priority_queue<Square, vector<Square>, SquareCompare> p_queue;

    p_queue.push(Square(N-1, N-1));
    in_i[N-1] = true;
    in_j[N-1] = true;

    while(!p_queue.empty()) {
    Square sq = p_queue.top();

    p_queue.pop();
    in_i[sq.i] = false;
    in_j[sq.j] = false;

    // cout << "pop " << sq.i << " " << sq.j << endl;

    if (sq.i > 0 && !in_i[sq.i - 1] && sq.i-1 >= sq.j) {
        p_queue.push(Square(sq.i-1, sq.j));
        in_i[sq.i-1] = true;
        in_j[sq.j] = true;
        // cout << "push " << sq.i-1 << " " << sq.j << endl;
    }
    if (sq.j > 0 && !in_j[sq.j-1] && sq.i >= sq.j - 1) {
        p_queue.push(Square(sq.i, sq.j-1));
        in_i[sq.i] = true;
        in_j[sq.j - 1] = true;
        // cout << "push " << sq.i << " " << sq.j-1 << endl;
    }

    if (sq.taxicab(p_queue.top())) {
        /* taxicab number */
        cout << sq << " " << p_queue.top() << endl;
        count++;
    }
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "there are " << count << " taxicab numbers with a, b, c, d < " << N << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Cheng If the priority queue outputs the same value multiple times (necessarily in a consecutive way since the priority queue outputs the values in order), then it means that there are elements in the matrix that are equal. In other words, M[i][j] = M[i'][j'] with (i, j) not equal to (i', j'). On the other hand M[i][j] = i^3 + j^3, hence you've found multiple ways to write an integer as the sum of two cubed integers.

Answer (score 16):

The answers given by Novneet Nov and user3017842 are both correct ideas for finding the taxicab numbers with storage O(N) using minHeap. 
Just a little bit more explanation why the minHeap of size N works. 
First, if you had all the sums (O(N^2)) and could sort them (O(N^2lgN)) you would just pick the duplicates as you traverse the sorted array. Well, in our case using a minHeap we can traverse in-order all the sums: we just need to ensure that the minHeap always contains the minimum unprocessed sum.

Now, we have a huge number of sums (O(N^2)). But, notice that this number can be split into N groups each of which has an easily defined minimum! 
(fix `a`, change `b` from `0 to N-1` => here are your `N` groups. The sum in one group with a smaller `b` is smaller than one with a bigger `b` in the same group - because `a` is the same).

> The minimum of union of these groups is in the union of mins of these
>   groups. Therefore, if you keep all minimums of these groups in the
>   minHeap you are guaranteed to have the total minimum in the minHeap.

Now, when you extract Min from the heap, you just add next smallest element from the group of this extracted min (so if you extracted `(a, b)` you add `(a, b+1)`) and you are guaranteed that your minHeap still contains the next unprocessed min of all the sums.

Comment: Finally I got it after your explanation. Thank you!

Comment: How's `(a,b) < (a,b+1)`, as you said "next smallest element from the group"?

Answer (score 11):

I found the solution/code here : [Time complexity O(N^2 logN), space complexity O(N)](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/Taxicab.java.html)
The solution is implemented by help of priority queues.

Reverse thinking can be easily done by looking at the code. It can be done in an array of size N because the min sums are deleted from the array after comparing to the next minimum and then the array is made to size N by adding a new sum - (i^3 + (j+1)^3).

A intuitive proof is here :

Initially, we have added (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),...,(N,N) in the min-priority queue.

Suppose a^+b^3=c^3+d^3, and (a,b) is the minimum that will be taken out of the priority queue next. To be able to detect this taxicab number, (c,d) must also be in the priority queue which would be taken out after (a,b).

Note: We would be adding (a,b+1) after extracting (a,b) so there is no way that extraction of (a,b) would result in addition of (c,d) to the priority queue, so it must already exist in the priority queue.

Now lets assume that (c,d) is not in the priority queue, because we haven't gotten to it yet. Instead, there is some (c,d−k) in the priority queue where k>0.

Since (a,b) is being taken out,
a^3+b^3≤c^3+(d−k)^3

However, a^3+b^3=c^3+d^3

Therefore,

c^3+d^3≤c^3+(d−k)^3
d≤d−k
k≤0

Since k>0, this is impossible. Thus our assumption can never come to pass.
Thus for every (a,b) which is being removed from the min-PQ, (c,d) is already in the min-PQ (or was just removed) if a^3+b^3=c^3+d^3

Answer (score 3):

version1 uses List and sorting

*O(n^2*logn) time and O(n^2) space*

```
    public static void Taxicab1(int n)
    {
        // O(n^2) time and O(n^2) space
        var list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j <= n; j++)
            {
                list.Add(i * i * i + j * j * j);
            }
        }

        // O(n^2*log(n^2)) time
        list.Sort();

        // O(n^2) time
        int prev = -1;
        foreach (var next in list)
        {
            if (prev == next)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prev);
            }
            prev = next;
        }
    }
```

version2 uses HashSet

*O(n^2) time and O(n^2) space*

```
    public static void Taxicab2(int n)
    {
        // O(n^2) time and O(n^2) space
        var set = new HashSet<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j <= n; j++)
            {
                int x = i * i * i + j * j * j;
                if (!set.Add(x))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

version3 uses min oriented [Priority Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue)

*O(n^2*logn) time and O(n) space*

```
    public static void Taxicab3(int n)
    {
        // O(n) time and O(n) space
        var pq = new MinPQ<SumOfCubes>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            pq.Push(new SumOfCubes(i, i));
        }

        // O(n^2*logn) time
        var sentinel = new SumOfCubes(0, 0);
        while (pq.Count > 0)
        {
            var current = pq.Pop();

            if (current.Result == sentinel.Result)
                Console.WriteLine($"{sentinel.A}^3+{sentinel.B}^3 = {current.A}^3+{current.B}^3 = {current.Result}");

            if (current.B <= n)
                pq.Push(new SumOfCubes(current.A, current.B + 1));

            sentinel = current;
        }
    }
```

where SummOfCubes

```
public class SumOfCubes : IComparable<SumOfCubes>
{
    public int A { get; private set; }
    public int B { get; private set; }
    public int Result { get; private set; }

    public SumOfCubes(int a, int b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        Result = a * a * a + b * b * b;
    }

    public int CompareTo(SumOfCubes other)
    {
        return Result.CompareTo(other.Result);
    }
}
```

[github](https://github.com/dlarionov/algorithms/tree/master/Part%20I/IQ/07%20-%20Priority%20Queues/Taxicab%20numbers)

Answer (score 2):

1. create an array: 1^3, 2^3, 3^3, 4^3, ....... k^3.  such that k^3 < N and (k+1)^3 > N. the array size would be ~ (N)^(1/3). the array is sorted order.
2. use 2sum technique ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928091/linear-time-algorithm-for-2-sum)) in lineal time proportional to the array size. if we find 2 pairs of numbers, that is a hit.
3. looping through step 2 by decreasing N by 1 each time.

This will use O(N^(1/3)) extra space and ~ O(N^(4/3)) time.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @ccjmne seems ok to me.

Comment: @vaxquis OMG you're right, what the heck??? It started out as a question! Ummm....what???

Answer (score 1):

A easy way of understanding [Time complexity O(N^2 logN), space complexity O(N)](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/Taxicab.java.html) is to think it as a merge of `N` sorted arrays plus a bookkeeping of the previously merged element.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can also do better on time (O (N ^ 2)) with O(N ^ 2) memory, using a hashmap to check if a pair of cubes has already be seen. In Python:

```
def find_taxicab_numbers(n: int) -> List[Tuple[int, int, int, int, int]]:
    """
    find all taxicab numbers smaller than n, i.e. integers that can be expressed as the sum of two cubes of positive
    integers in two different ways so that a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3.
    Time: O(n ^ 2) (two loops, one dict lookup). Space: O(n ^ 2)) (all possible cubes)
    :param n: upper bound for a, b, c, d
    :return: list of tuples of int: a, b, c, d, and taxicab numbers
    """
    cubes = [i ** 3 for i in range(n)]
    seen_sum_cubes = dict()  # mapping sum cubes -> a, b
    taxicabs = list()  # list of a, b, c, d, taxicab
    # check all possible sums of cubes
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            sum_cubes = cubes[i] + cubes[j]
            if sum_cubes in seen_sum_cubes:
                prev_i, prev_j = seen_sum_cubes[sum_cubes]
                taxicabs.append((i, j, prev_i, prev_j, sum_cubes))
            else:
                seen_sum_cubes[sum_cubes] = (i, j)
    return taxicabs
```

Comment: If your n is 1e9, it's going to run into an Memory error most likely, while computing cubes for all numbers in range(1, 1000000000)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a simple brute-force algorithm with proper bounds solves it in time proportional to **n^1.33** and space proportional to **n**. Or could anyone point me to the place where I'm mistaken?

Consider 4 nested loops, each running from 1 to **cubic root of n**. Using these loops we can go over all possible combinations of 4 values and find the pairs forming taxicab numbers. It means each loop takes time proportional to **cubic root of n**, or **n^(1/3)**. Multiply this value 4 times and get:

```
(n^(1/3)^4 = n^(4/3) = n^1.33
```

I wrote a solution in JavaScript and benchmarked it, and it seems to be working. One caveat is that *the result is only partially sorted*.

Here is my JavaScript code (it's not optimal yet, could be optimized even more):

```
function taxicab(n) {
  let a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d = 1,
  cubeA = a**3 + b**3,
  cubeB = c**3 + d**3,
  results = [];

  while (cubeA < n) { // loop over a
    while (cubeA < n) { // loop over b
      // avoid running nested loops if this number is already in results
      if (results.indexOf(cubeA) === -1) {
       while (cubeB <= cubeA) { // loop over c
        while (cubeB <= cubeA) { // loop over d
          if (cubeB === cubeA && a!=c && a!=d) { // found a taxicab number!
            results.push(cubeA);
          }
          d++;
          cubeB = c**3 + d**3;
        } // end loop over d
        c++;
        d = c;
        cubeB = c**3 + d**3;
       } // end loop over c
      }
      b++;
      cubeA = a**3 + b**3;
      c = d = 1;
      cubeB = c**3 + d**3;
    } // end loop over d
    a++;
    b = a;
    cubeA = a**3 + b**3;
  } // end loop over a

  return results;
}
```

Running `taxicab(1E8)` takes around 30 seconds in a browser console and yields 485 numbers as a result. Ten times smaller value `taxicab(1E7)` (10 millions) takes almost 1.4 seconds and yields 150 numbers. `10^1.33 * 1.4 = 29.9`, i.e. multiplying **n** by **10** leads to the running time increased by **10^1.33** times. The result array is unsorted, but after quickly sorting it we get correct result, as it seems:

```
[1729, 4104, 13832, 20683, 32832, 39312, 40033, 46683, 64232, 65728,
110656, 110808, 134379, 149389, 165464, 171288, 195841, 216027, 216125,
262656, 314496, 320264, 327763, 373464, 402597, 439101, 443889, 513000, 
513856, 515375, 525824, 558441, 593047, 684019, 704977, 805688, 842751, 
885248, 886464, 920673, 955016, 984067, 994688, 1009736, 1016496, 1061424,
1073375, 1075032, 1080891, 1092728, 1195112, 1260441, 1323712, 1331064,
1370304, 1407672, 1533357, 1566728, 1609272, 1728216, 1729000, 1734264,
1774656, 1845649, 2048391, 2101248, 2301299, 2418271, 2515968, 2562112,
2585375, 2622104, 2691451, 2864288, 2987712, 2991816, 3220776, 3242197,
3375001, 3375008, 3511872, 3512808, 3551112, 3587409, 3628233, 3798613,
3813992, 4033503, 4104000, 4110848, 4123000, 4174281, 4206592, 4342914,
4467528, 4505949, 4511808, 4607064, 4624776, 4673088, …]
```

Here is a code for benchmarking:

```
// run taxicab(n) for k trials and return the average running time
function benchmark(n, k) {
  let t = 0;
  k = k || 1; // how many times to repeat the trial to get an averaged result

  for(let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    let t1 = new Date();
    taxicab(n);
    let t2 = new Date();
    t += t2 - t1;
  }
  return Math.round(t/k);
}
```

Finally, I tested it:

```
let T = benchmark(1E7, 3); // 1376 - running time for n = 10 million
let T2 = benchmark(2E7, 3);// 4821 - running time for n = 20 million
let powerLaw = Math.log2(T2/T); // 1.3206693816701993
```

So it means time is proportional to **n^1.32** in this test. Repeating this many times with different values always yields around the same result: from **1.3** to **1.4**.

Comment: And by the way, there seems to be another solution proportional to n^1.66: one loop over n numbers and 2 loops over cubic root of n numbers, i.e. n^1 * n^(2/3) = n^(5/3)
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taxicab-numbers/

Comment: Found some comprehensive implementations of different algorithms on this problem: https://github.com/anars/TaxicabNumbers
The inner loop over "d" variable can be omitted at all by calculating its value.

Comment: This answer misunderstands than n is the limit for how big a, b, c, and d are, not how big the taxicab number is, which is much, much larger.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we will **construct** the taxicab numbers instead of searching for them. The range we will use to construct a taxicab number i.e `Ta(2)` will go up to `n^1/3` not `n`. Because if you cube a number bigger than `n^1/3` it will be bigger than `n` and also we can't cube negative numbers to prevent that case by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number). We will use a HashSet to remember the sums of two cubed numbers in the algorithm. This will help us to lookup previous cubed sums in `O(1)` time while we are iterating over every possible pair of numbers in the range I mentioned earlier.

Time complexity: `O(n^2/3)`

Space complexity: `O(n^1/3)`

```py
def taxicab_numbers(n: int) -> list[int]:
    taxicab_numbers = []
    max_num = math.floor(n ** (1. / 3.))
    seen_sums = set()
    for i in range(1, max_num + 1):
        for j in range(i, max_num + 1):
            cube_sum = i ** 3 + j ** 3
            if cube_sum in seen_sums:
                taxicab_numbers.append(cube_sum)
            else:
                seen_sums.add(cube_sum)
    return taxicab_numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
    import java.util.*;

    public class A5Q24 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter number:");
            int n = sc.nextInt();

            // start checking every int less than the input
            for (int a = 2;a <= n;a++) {
                int count = 0;
                // number of ways that number be expressed in sum of two number cubes
                for (int i = 1; Math.pow(i, 3) < a; i++) {
                    // if the cube of number smaller is greater than the number than it goes out
                    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                        if (Math.pow(i, 3) + Math.pow(j, 3) == a)
                            count++;
                    }
                }
                if (count == 2)
                    System.out.println(a);
            }
            sc.close();
        }
    }
```